# NodeJS authentication with passport using facebook strategy

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, sdk, passport.js

I'm working on a project in NodeJS where I want to login using username / password or by using facebook. I've searched and found there is a module for NodeJS called http://passportjs.org/ which integrates different strategies for different social platforms ( facebook, twitter etc ).

After being logged in I also want to acces different information about the user such as friends list, possibility to post on their wall and so on. From what I see facebook strategy for passport doesn't support this.

My second option is to use https://github.com/amachang/facebook-node-sdk . This allows me to login, and also get the friends list, post on user wall, etc.

Is it possible to use both ? Login using facebook strategy from passport, and then pass the token to the facebook sdk api to use it for posting on user wall.

What is the best approach ? How would you see the integration with facebook ?

Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well passport does in fact support this. You can specify permissions in the scope object like this

```
app.get('/auth/facebook',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['read_stream', 'publish_actions'] })
);
```

This is mentioned in the [passport docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/). [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/) is the list of permissions that you can actually request from Facebook.

Comment: Thank you very much, for your help. I didn't knew that. Can you please show me how can I use passport to preform different actions, such as writing on user's wall or getting the list of friends ? I would appreciate that. Thanks again

Comment: @SilVeRAleCS with passport you can get tokens with permissions to get a list of users friends or write on their wall. Once you get the access token you should either use the facebook api or the node facebook sdk to actually perform those actions.

Comment: Super helpful. Thank you! The Graph API Explorer actually explains this concept of specifying permissions, and then request data from the endpoint very well: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/